# Angular Js - Changing views not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to change view from the controller but it isn't working.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('vla', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function ($routeProvider){
           $routeProvider
            .when('/view1',
                  {
                  controller: 'loginController',
                  templateUrl: 'partials/loginView.html'
                  })
           .when('/view2',
                 {
                 controller: 'noteController',
                 templateUrl: 'partials/videoView.html'
                 })
           .when('/view3',
                 {
                 controller: 'videoListController',
                 templateUrl: 'partials/videoListView.html'
                 })
           .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/view1' });
});
```

view: videoListView.html

```
<div class="video" data-ng-click="selectVideo(video)" ng-repeat="video in videos">
        <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in video|orderBy:orderByField:videoName">

            {{key}}: {{val}} </br>

        </div>
</div>
```

controller.js

```
app.controller('videoListController', function($scope,getVideoListService){

           $scope.selectVideo = function(video){
           $location.url('/view2');
           }
});
```

I have tried the following but none seem to work

```
$location.url('#/view2');
$location.url('/view2');
$location.path('/view2');
$location.path('#/view2');
```

When inserting a link on a view page such as

```
<a href="#/view2"</a>click
```

the page is correctly routed, would appreciate any help on changing views from the controller.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATE:

I should have seen this before, but `$location` is a service you aren't passing in.

```
//Need to pass in $location
app.controller('videoListController', function($scope, $location, getVideoListService){

   $scope.selectVideo = function(video){
      $location.url('/view2');
   }
});
```

To help you out in furthering your Angular-foo, I would take a look at [John Lindquist's fantastic videos at egghead.io](https://egghead.io/). Most of the Angular videos are free to watch.

Aside from that, the [Dependency Injection](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) section from the official [Angular Developers Guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide) is going to be a good read.

---

Based on what you are describing, my guess is that your function isn't being called at all. Try adding some console output to see if it get's called, and then working to fix your issues.

```
$scope.selectVideo = function(video){

    console.log('Changing the route...');

    $location.path('/view2');
}
```

Check the console output for errors by opening up the developer tools.

Comment: It prints it to console, however it says Error: Can't find variable: $location

Comment: DOH! I should have seen that in your sample! I'll update my answer

Comment: @Cylus27 - Also added some links that should help out a lot. Those videos are an absolute must for any Angular Dev.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead

```
$window.location = "/view2";
```

or on click of a button which in turn uses a function:

```
$scope.randomFunctionAppears= function() {

    $window.location = "/view2";

};
```

Comment: I'm very new to this so excuse any stupid comments, but when putting an alert before and after the $window.location = "/view2"; only the initial alert is shown

Comment: I have used it in every Angular Project of mine and it works. Don't know why not working in yours. This appends your current URL. Here is the documentation on it. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window

Comment: In case of alert because may be your $window.location must be giving some error. Check in console(press F12)